# How to sign google street view request from python library?

Tags: python, google-maps, google-street-view

I am trying to do a decent number of queries to the google maps static street view api. I am providing my Api key and it was working well but it seems when it gets to a certain number of scrapes done I start getting forbidden errors returned by google. After some exploration I have determined that these are because i am not signing these requests with my signing secret.

After exploring the google cloud console i discovered my signing secret, which looks something like this:

```
'sadfafKL2-pw43434sPSds2DDk=' #(this is a random string, not actual signing secret)
```

My confusion now centers around how to pass this signing secret to my google maps api request params using the import google_streetview.api package. The current code I was using before which takes the apikey but not the signing secret is:

```
import google_streetview.api
params = [{
    'size': '640x640',  
    'location':  "34.122342,-118.73721", 
    'key': 'my_key'
}]
results = google_streetview.api.results(params)
```

How can i add my signing secret to this to stop the forbidden errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the instructions from Google's documentation to create a digital signature https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/get-api-key#dig-sig-key

You can find sample code in Python [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/get-api-key#sample-code-for-url-signing).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The code sample provided by Google in the documentation linked in the accepted answer is outdated (Python 2.x?). The file in GitHub they link to hasn't been updated since 2016! I am submitting a PR with an updated file for Python 3., but the repo hasn't been updated in over 2 years, so who knows if they'll look at it. So here is the code, just in case:

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
import urllib.parse as urlparse


def sign_url(input_url=None, secret=None):
    """ Sign a request URL with a URL signing secret.
      Usage:
      from urlsigner import sign_url
      signed_url = sign_url(input_url=my_url, secret=SECRET)
      Args:
      input_url - The URL to sign
      secret    - Your URL signing secret
      Returns:
      The signed request URL
  """

    if not input_url or not secret:
        raise Exception("Both input_url and secret are required")

    url = urlparse.urlparse(input_url)

    # We only need to sign the path+query part of the string
    url_to_sign = url.path + "?" + url.query

    # Decode the private key into its binary format
    # We need to decode the URL-encoded private key
    decoded_key = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(secret)

    # Create a signature using the private key and the URL-encoded
    # string using HMAC SHA1. This signature will be binary.
    signature = hmac.new(decoded_key, str.encode(url_to_sign), hashlib.sha1)

    # Encode the binary signature into base64 for use within a URL
    encoded_signature = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signature.digest())

    original_url = url.scheme + "://" + url.netloc + url.path + "?" + url.query

    # Return signed URL
    return original_url + "&signature=" + encoded_signature.decode()
```

Comment: My pull request has been accepted, so the Python code example in the official GitHub repo is now updated for Python 3